# Replace angular UI-GRID selection RowButton with checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angular-ui-grid

I need to replace the UI grid selection header content with a regular checkbox instead of default OK button.
 I was able to insert checkbox but I am not able to control the row checkbox value based on column header checked checkbox. 
 Requirement: When the column header checkbox is selected, all the row checkboxes should be selected. 
  When a row checkbox is unselected then the column header checkbox should be unselected.

Select/unselect checkbox works but I should be able to control the row checkbox based on column header checkbox.

I am struggling with scope here. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Plunker Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ji7gLbfQTohnEj04mYFM?p=preview

```
 $templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionRowHeaderButtons',
    "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons \" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}\"><input style=\"margin: 0; vertical-align: middle\" type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"rowSelected\" ng-click=\"grid.appScope.clickConditionRow(rowSelected) && selectButtonClick(row, $event)\">&nbsp;</div>"
  );
```

Comment: can you provide us with some piece of code ?

Comment: Please provide a plunkr link replicating the issue.

Comment: Hello @Druid thanks for taking a look. I have added the links to plunkr which has the code and a link to show the running plnkr. I am unable to preview in the plunker and hence provided a seperate link.

Comment: Hello @SaiGiridhar, I have added the plunkr links. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the fix http://plnkr.co/edit/aBmgnNXQ4fL0npJHzsfG?p=preview

Header checkbox template:

```
<div class="ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons" ng-class="{'ui-grid-all-selected': grid.selection.selectAll}" ng-if="grid.options.enableSelectAll"><input style="margin: 0; vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" ng-model="grid.selection.selectAll" ng-click="grid.selection.selectAll=!grid.selection.selectAll;headerButtonClick($event)"></div>
```

Row checkbox template:

```
<div class="ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons" ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}" ><input style="margin: 0; vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" ng-model="row.isSelected" ng-click="row.isSelected=!row.isSelected;selectButtonClick(row, $event)">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @SaiGiridhar. Thats exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Row checkbox template worked for me but not Header checkbox template